# Sort the letters in each string alphabetically Python function

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I want to write a function that takes a list of strings, sort the letters in each string, and then sort the full list.

So I created a list of strings "a". This code works perfectly, but is there any way to split the code for b variable? I want this function to sort the letters in each string first and then sort the full list.

```
a = ['hi' , 'hello', 'at', 'this', 'there', 'from']
def string_fun(a):
    for i in a:
        b= sorted(''.join(sorted(i)) for i in a)
    return(b)
string_fun(a)
```

I was trying this:

```
a = ['hi' , 'hello', 'at', 'this', 'there', 'from']
def string_fun(a):
    for i in a:
        b=''.join(sorted(i))
        for i in b:
            c= sorted()
                  
    return(c)
string_fun(a)
```

But I get an error "sorted expected 1 argument, got 0"

Comment: have you tried 'for i in a' instead of 'for i in len(a)'

Comment: Try this: print(sorted(''.join(sorted(el)) for el in a))

Comment: Doesn't sound like a meaningful end goal. Why do you want that?

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the syntax for `for`-loops in python. When you write `for x in a`, variable `x` is not an index to be used to get an element as `a[x]`. Variable `x` *is* the element.

So you can write:

```py
result = []
for x in a:
  result.append(''.join(sorted(x)))
result.sort()
```

Or equivalently:

```py
result = []
for i in range(len(a)):
  result.append(''.join(sorted(a[i])))
result.sort()
```

Or equivalently, use a list comprehension:

```py
result = sorted(''.join(sorted(x)) for x in a)
```

Please take some time to read more about loops and list comprehensions in python:

- [loops in python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements);
- [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).